# Error when exporting a line-string vector layer to GPX - the exported GPX contains no coordinates

Tags: qgis, export, linestring, gpx

I've read [these answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/how-can-i-export-a-linestring-to-a-gpx-file-in-qgis), but I seem to be having a more basic problem. When I open the exported GPX in notepad, there are no coordinates at all.

[image: Screengrab of my project. The linestring I want to export is aqua blue]

Screengrab of my project. The linestring I want to export is aqua blue.

[image]

Screengrab of the error I'm getting (irrelevant for now I think).

Comment: That seems like a relevant error to me - don't call one of your attributes `id`

Comment: @IanTurton How do you remove all attributes (tried)? I don't think this is the issue though - if you read the related stack exchange question I linked, other people have received that error but the GPX file still has all the information they need. It just has some extra noise. I'll find a way to get rid of excess noise in the file, I just want the coordinates exported. Thanks

Comment: and you have checked skip attributes (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15837/79)?

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton - you were right, QGIS automatically preselcts the "id" field for export in a collapsed field of the export page. On Friday a friend and I did ten passes on that mountain and recorded the GPX, but of course it bounced around in cliff lines, so the QGIS hand-drawn GPX looks better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If QGIS produces an error while exporting, your GPX file won't contain the lat/long coordinates you are after. To avoid the error displayed in your screenshot, expand all the fields in QGIS's export screen and deselect anything that is not necessary (for example "id" in your screenshot).